# UIImagePickerController front camera mirror image

Tags: ios7, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, front-camera

I have an app that uses the camera to take picture. I am building something like a selfie with a celebrity.
With front camera, user can adjust according to the overlay photo and take the picture.

The problem is that the front camera picture gets mirrored. So now the image is not at the same place with respective to the overlay image.

Is there a way to mirror the image after user clicks on capture button?

Comment: Post some code and someone can point you in the right direction.  Right now my answer would be "yes, just mirror the image".  There is a whole process when using the camera and the capture button.  So somewhere in that process you can mirror the image, or mirror the celeb overlay if they switch to the front camera.

Comment: Also.. given that the app is a selfie app.. it's designed to use the front camera.  So yeah.. mirror the celeb photo would be an option.  If they use the back camera they'll just get undesired results.  I think the real question you should ask is "how can I disable the back camera and force them to only use the front camera?"

Comment: I don't want to force only the front camera, the back camera should also work. The app is not a selfie app, its just one of the feature. The overlay also includes company icon.. so user can take photo of something else as well

Comment: Then the answer is really just "yes". You can mirror the image after the user clicks the capture button.  I'll work on a real answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can mirror an image right after the user clicks on the capture button.  The trick will be knowing when to and when not to.  Or knowing if really you should be flipping your overlay.  I would think you'll want to flip your overlay and not the image.. But that part is your logic to figure out.  Here's how I would flip the image:

```
- (void)imageTaken:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIImage *image = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // determine if image needs to be flipped.  Maybe based on the size which tells you which camera was used.  Or maybe using the EXIF data.  That wasn't your question though so..
    bool imageNeedsFlipped = ... whatever your logic is
    if (imageNeedsFlipped) image = [self flipImageHorizontally:image];
    // then do your thing with your image..
}

- (UIImage *) flipImageHorizontally:(UIImage *)originalImage
{
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform flipHorizontal = CGAffineTransformMake(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, tempImageView.frame.size.height, 0.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipHorizontal);

    [tempImageView.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *flippedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return flippedImage;
}
```

But as I said in the comments. The image is NOT flipped when you get it from the controller.  It is only flipped when you're seeing yourself on the screen and you're using the front camera.  Do this test.. turn on the camera and switch to the front facing camera.. hold up your left hand.  The screen shows you like a mirror.  The hand on the left of the screen is the one held up.  Now take the picture and look at it in the library.  The hand on the right is now the one held up.  It's not flipping reality when it saves the photo.  It's flipping reality when it's previewing it to you.

So really I think you are approaching it the wrong way.  The overlay is what needs to be flipped but only when they're using the front camera.  But that is up to you and how you want your app to work.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to flip the overlay image when the front camera is ON.
The problem in that case would be ...
1) User turns on front facing camera (overlay image is flipped)
2) User clicks on "Capture"
3) iOS shows a preview mode
   In this preview mode, the camera image is flipped but now my overlay image is wrong.
Since I don't have control over the preview page, the only option I have is to disable controls and create my own controls. Which mean I have to implement almost everything that iOS provides.. e.g. (capture, cancel, retake, flip camera, flash) and the preview page as well

Comment: I go to a preview view after the photo is taken where I have a accept / retake button.  On that screen you could also have a flop overlay. But again. It's not hard to know if the image was front or back camera when you get to there cause of the size of the captured image.  So check that size or check the exif data and overlay the appropriately flipped overlay.

Comment: Thanks badweasel, I built my own camera view and preview view. I had to build the overlay for camera view with Cancel and Capture buttons and then when user clicks on capture I create my own Preview page and mirrored the original image. I also added Retake and Use photo links on my preview page. 
I will create something in github to solve this problem since I am assuming many people would need this feature and I didn't find any easy solution out.

Thanks for all your comments, it helped me think over other possible solutions!!